# iOS Complete Data Protection + application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I've got an iPad app that uses Complete Data Protection to encrypt the contents of the app unless the device is unlocked and running.  This was mandated by the client, and is working as expected.

A second business requirement is that we run a few web service calls in the background.  This is accomplished using the new `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler` available in iOS 7.  I need to pull a few numbers out of a local SQLite database to compare to the result of the web service however, in order to know if I need to kickoff a background download.  This is failing.

Is there a way to configure data protection so my app can read from the SQLite database while in the background?

Can permissions be set on a file by file basis?

Failing that, can anyone suggest a work-around?  NSUserDefaults?  plist files?  Something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read from the sqlite database while `NSFileProtectionComplete` is enabled and the device is locked. However, Apple describes how to handle this type of situation in the 2013 WWDC video "What's New with Multitasking" @ https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/ at around 44:00.

Because your SQLite file is set to `NSFileProtectionComplete`, you cannot write to or read from it while the device is locked. What you should do is write any new data (downloaded in the background when the device is locked) to a separate file on disk at level `NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen`. This will allow you to write the data to disk and the data will become protected when you close the file. When protected data becomes available (the device is unlocked) you should merge the data into your database.

You may want to try creating a file on disk that contains the information you need to determine when to make a new data request. If you set this file to level `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` you should still be able to read it while the device is locked.

Answer (score 0):

> This is failing

What exactly is failing? Inserting into the coredata database? Getting the details from your webserver?

Any chance you could post some of the code in your `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler` method so that we can get a better idea of what exactly is going on?

Comment: 'Error while updating. 'authorization denied'' is the the error from SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

It took some work, but we did find a way to be able to run code in the background and still protect our sensitive data.

Rather than using Complete Data Protection at the app level, we implement it on a file-by-file basis as needed.  Not everything needs to be protected, just the files that contain sensative information.  Those get Complete Data Protection added to them at run time with this code:

```
NSDictionary *completeAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: NSFileProtectionComplete forKey: NSFileProtectionKey];
BOOL result = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes: completeAttr ofItemAtPath: fileName error: &err];
if(result) {
    NSLog(@"File protected %@", fileName);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to protect file %@ error %@", fileName, err);
}
```

By using this approach, and separating the sensative data from the non-sensative data, we can run in the background and still access some information without exposing all of it.